# Как сделать отображение ссылки в сообщении?

Tags: php, html, javascript

Есть текстовая переменная определенная вот так:

```
$text = "(Автоматически сгенерированное сообщение) вы приглашены для  вступления в коалицию ".$myrowcoal['name']." для ознакомления перейдите по ссылке 
\nhttp://www.nw.com/coalition.php?id=".$id."\n";
```

Проблема в том, что когда текст этой переменной передается сообщением на сайте пользователю, то он выглядит как текст, а не как ссылка.

Как можно сделать так, чтобы на нее можно было нажимать?

Comment: пробовал еще вот так

    $text = "(Автоматически сгенерированное сообщение) вы приглашены    для<br> вступления в коалицию ".$myrowcoal['name']." для ознакомления    перейдите по ссылке 
    <a href='coalition.php?id=".$id.">Ссылка</a>";

но при выводе в сообщении он просто выдает "(Автоматически сгенерированное сообщение) вы приглашены для
вступления в коалицию Код Гиас для ознакомления перейдите по ссылке" без куска хтмл

Answer (score 0, accepted):

все разобрался сделал так

```
$text = "(Автоматически сгенерированное сообщение) вы приглашены для<br> вступления в   коалицию ".$myrowcoal['name']." для ознакомления перейдите по ссылке 
http://www.nw.com/coalition.php?id=$id";
```

и при помощи функции

```
function link_it($text)
{
    $text= preg_replace("/(^|[\n ])([\w]*?)((ht|f)tp(s)?:\/\/[\w]+[^ \,\"\n\r\t<]*)/is", "$1$2<a href=\"$3\" >$3</a>", $text);
$text= preg_replace("/(^|[\n ])([\w]*?)((www|ftp)\.[^ \,\"\t\n\r<]*)/is", "$1$2<a href=\"http://$3\" >$3</a>", $text);
$text= preg_replace("/(^|[\n ])([a-z0-9&\-_\.]+?)@([\w\-]+\.([\w\-\.]+)+)/i", "$1<a href=\"mailto:$2@$3\">$2@$3</a>", $text);
return($text);
}
```

превратил в ссылку

```
$text = link_it($text);
```

и все заработало) всем спасибо за содействие)

Answer (score 0):

```
$text = "(Автоматически сгенерированное сообщение) вы приглашены для  вступления в коалицию ".$myrowcoal['name']." для ознакомления перейдите по ссылке 
    \n<a href='http://www.nw.com/coalition.php?id=".$id."'>http://www.nw.com/coalition.php?id=".$id."</a>\n";
```

Так?

Comment: да сообщение заработало но в БД не заносится((


    $text = "(Автоматически сгенерированное сообщение) вы приглашены   для<br> вступления в коалицию ".$myrowcoal['name']." для ознакомления   перейдите по ссылке 
     \n<a href='http://www.nw.com/coalition.php?    id=".$id."'>http://www.nw.com/coalition.php?id=".$id."</a>\n";


    $result0 = mysql_query("INSERT INTO dialogues (id1, id2, date,   text, stat) VALUES ('$myrow2[id]','$iduser','$date','$text',   '1')",$db);//заносим в базу сообщение

Comment: Заносится только если убрать \n<a href='http://www.nw.com/coalition.php?    id=".$id."'>http://www.nw.com/coalition.php?id=".$id."</a>\n

Comment: а вы пропустите сообщение через mysql_real_escape_string

Answer (score 0):

```
echo $text = "(Автоматически сгенерированное сообщение) вы приглашены    для<br> вступления в коалицию ".$myrowcoal['name']."
     для ознакомления    перейдите по ссылке."." <a href='coalition.php?id=".$id."'>Ссылка</a>";
```

Comment: та же история что и выше в БД не заносится\